# expiration set but still showing as not set

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to speed out our site and using gtmertix.com to check.

I've been adding / removing code all day and have this in the htaccess file.

I have the following set in .htaccess -

```
# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
</filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

But i still get the following messages when i check on gtmetrix.com

```
http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css (expiration not specified)
http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/goal.min.js (expiration not specified)
http://buttons-config.sharethis.com/js/58ac087b20428700112b0504.js (1 minute)
http://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js (10 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/247608415681348?v=2.7.10 (20 minutes)
https://google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

What can i do to add expiration to the above ? or is it not possible ?